# configuring zookeeper without zkcli

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I've got a test zookeeper configuration up and running and can use the zkcli command to create a running cluster (in this case managing solr).

Is there anyway to do this by passing a configuration file to zookeeper rather than piping commands through zkcli?

Comment: This is using zookeeper v3.4.6 and solr v5.1.0.

If I use `/opt/solr/bin/start` in my startup script, it automatically finds my core in /var/solr/data/production and runs in stand-alone mode. If I change the command to `/opt/solr/bin/start -cloud -z localhost:2181` I get the error **Could not load conf for core production: Error loading solr config from solrconfig.xml**

Comment: If I run these commands   
    `/opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd upconfig -zkhost 127.0.0.1:2181 -d /var/solr/data/production/conf -n core_prod`  
    `/opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd linkconfig --zkhost 127.0.0.1:2181 -collection production -confname core_prod -s /var/solr/data  `
    `/opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -cmd bootstrap -zkhost 127.0.0.1:2181 -solrhome /var/solr/data  `

 and start solr with `/opt/solr/bin/start -cloud -z localhost:2181`, all comes up as I want. I just want to be able to achieve this without the manual steps